# doGet and doPost in one class

Tags: java, servlets, post, get

When i try to use doGet and doPost in one class and pass parameters using post method I get

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

But when I comment doGet it works just fine. Why is that? `doGet` and `doPost` can't be used in the same class?

Here is class code:

```
package pl.javastart.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class wypisz_parametry extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1321321321L;

/*public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)    throws ServletException, IOException {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  String parametr1 = request.getParameter("parametr1");
  String parametr2 = request.getParameter("parametr2");
  String parametr3 = request.getParameter("parametr3");

  out.println("Wczytanie 3 parametrow z zadania :");
  out.println(parametr1);
  out.println(parametr2);
  out.println(parametr3);
  }*/

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("Wczytanie 3 parametrow z zadania :");
    out.println(request.getParameter("parametr1"));
    out.println(request.getParameter("parametr2"));
    out.println(request.getParameter("parametr3"));
}

}
```

And html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Przyklad POST</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<H1 ALIGN="CENTER">Przyklad HTTP POST</H1>

<FORM ACTION="http://localhost:8080/Parameters/wypisz_parametry"
  METHOD="POST">
Parametr 1:
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="parametr1"><BR>
Parametr 2:
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="parametr2"><BR>
Parametr 3:
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="parametr3"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Wyslij">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Parameters</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.javastart.servlets.wypisz_parametry</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Parameters</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/wypisz_parametry</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Probably a problem with your url mappings. Please add your web.xml to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Both `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods can call the same servlet. So the issue is absolutely with something else. Maybe there is something wrong with your URL mappings in `web.xml`.

There is at least one issue with mapping:
On page we have:

```
ACTION="http://localhost:8080/Parameters/wypisz_parametry"
```

But in `web.xml` we expect:

```
ACTION="http://localhost:8080/wypisz_parametry"
```

Also it would be better to use relative path:

```
ACTION="/wypisz_parametry"
```

Comment: Then why it works? And i think that in web.xml we expect http://localhost:8080/Parameters/wypisz_parametry because /Parameters is add by default, because it's project name.

Comment: Strange, but servlet name should be not part of URL. Please look for example to java servlet tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm . Servlet name exists to be used in web.xml only, because same servlet can be mapped for different URLs, so in this case we will have one servlet declaration and several servlet mappings.

Answer (score -2):

here in the html code action part you have mentioned the method as post. when you choose post method get method doesn't work